Google Drive API Get file metedata
Does anyone know how to use the GoggleDrive API to get files that are in the Shared Drives category.
I have a API call that I can use to get metadata via FileID which
works for files that are shared with me, but when I attempt to get by a fileID that is on a shared Drive, I get an error " File Not Found.".
See Code Below with output:

def GetFileInfoById(TheFileId):

    service = authenticate()
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().get(fileId=TheFileId,
        fields="id, name, md5Checksum, webViewLink").execute()
    pprint(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  GetFileInfoById('  FILE ID Here')


The output I get is :
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/ File ID Here ?fields=id%2C+name%2Cmd5Checksum%2CwebViewLink&
alt=json returned "File not found: 1xJImDFvjIEJlLKUxFqzarm6fSWV8Vlxe.". Details: 
"[{'message': 'File not found: File ID Here.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 
'location': 'fileId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">

This code works as expected for files I own and files shared with me. I am getting a list
of file ID's from google API - that includes my shared Drive (I used the corpora='AllDrives' parameter in the list call).  Is there a way to include all of the drives in the get call? The list call did not include everything until I added the paramerters...

what code are you using for authorization?

Using the usual credential code that you see in the quick starts for python. That's working fine. The supportsAllDrives parameter is what I needed.

If you are trying to pull files within your Shared drives section via the Drive API get method, you may need to use the supportsAllDrives Query parameter. Without it being set to true in your API call, it produces the same HttpError 404 error.

supportsAllDrives boolean○ Whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives.

Your API call should look something like this:
# Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().get(fileId=TheFileId,
                                  supportsAllDrives=True,  # Add supportsAllDrives parameter
                                  fields="id, name, md5Checksum, webViewLink").execute()

Demo

I did a quick test by pulling a file in a shared drive folder using the supportsAllDrives parameter (true) and it returned the file response as seen below:








